# Como remover pacotes não usados na pasta node_modules com o comando NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

Eu instalei alguns pacotes do `NodeJS` via `npm install`. Porém depois decidi remover alguns. Mesmo quando eu instalo novamente, as pastas dos pacotes que não estou usando permanecem lá.

No `composer` do PHP, quando não usamos mais um pacote (quer dizer, removemos ele da lista de dependências do arquivo de configuração `json`), o mesmo é removido.

Tem como fazer isso no `Npm` do `NodeJS`?

Comment: Não sei se resolve seu problema, mas selecionar as pastas dos pacotes e apagar, elimina os pacotes também.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nos projetos onde o há o arquivo `package.json`, além do *uninstall* já mencionado na resposta anterior, você pode utilizar o comando:

```
node prune
```

Simplesmente edite o arquivo `package.json` para que ele contenha apenas as dependências que você utiliza e rode o comando que ele vai eliminar todos os pacotes que estão no `node_modules` e que você não referencia no `package.json`.

É recomendado também que no `package.json` você coloque no script de *postinstall* o comando `npm prune` para que após uma atualização de versão por exemplo, os pacotes não mais utilizados sejam removidos.

Exemplo de `package.json` com *script* de *postinstall*:

```
 {
   "name": "teste",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "Teste",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "postinstall": "npm prune"
   },
   "author": "bigous",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "luaparse": "^0.2.1"
   }
 }
```

Neste exemplo, qualquer pacote, exceto o `luaparse@0.2.x`, será removido do `node_modules` com o comando `node prune` ou após um `npm install` sem mais parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar os pacotes `npm install <nome_pacote>`

Para remover `npm uninstall <nome_pacote>`

Comment: Mas tem que remover um por um? Ele não reconhece automaticamente como o composer faz?

Comment: Bom se não estou enganado, você pode usar o comando `npm prune` , ele vai "rebildar" o arquivo `package.json` e só vai deixar instalado os pacotes que estiverem descritos neste arquivo , o restante ele remove.

Comment: Ah, sim. eu tentei usar esse aí, também rsrsrs. Na resposta em inglês fala que ele funciona, vou testar

Comment: Por que negativaram a resposta do rapaz ?